# Rerender is not triggered when changing the props

Tags: reactjs

I have some code for a Rubiks cube color picker app. When the user clicks on a square, the color should change to the currently selected color, however, the child of the root component is not rerendered for some reason when its props change.

I've tried using useEffect to trigger the rerender but to no avail. I did manage to get it to work by having a useState in the child that was set to a random number when the user clicks on a square and by that way a rerender was triggered - but there must be better solutions than that.

The parent:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./Cube.css";
import Side from "./Side";

const sides = ["T", "F", "L", "R", "B", "D"];
let initColors = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 54; i++) {
  initColors[i] = "blue";
}

const Cube = () => {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(initColors);
  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState("green");

  console.log(colors);

  const handleColorChange = (i) => {
    let copy = colors;
    copy[i] = selectedColor;
    setColors(copy);
  };

  return (
    <div className="grid-container">
      {sides.map((side, i) => (
        <div className={side}>
          <Side setColor={handleColorChange} i={i * 9} colors={colors} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cube;
```

The child:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import "./Cube.css";

const Side = (props) => {
  const { setColor, i, colors } = props;

  const handleClick = (i) => {
    setColor(i);
  };

  useEffect(() => {}, [colors]);

  let render = [];

  for (let j = i; j < i + 9; j++) {
    render.push(
      <Cube onClick={(e) => handleClick(j)} color={colors[j]}>
        {j}
      </Cube>
    );
  }

  return <Container>{render}</Container>;
};

const Container = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  height: 100%;
`;

const Cube = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: ${(props) => props.color};
`;

export default Side;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the child component to render, its props need to change.
React perform a shallow check. so if the prop is an object it checks only the reference.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./Cube.css";
import Side from "./Side";

const sides = ["T", "F", "L", "R", "B", "D"];
let initColors = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 54; i++) {
  initColors[i] = "blue";
}

const Cube = () => {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(initColors);
  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState("green");

  console.log(colors);

  const handleColorChange = (i) => {
    // Change this:
    let copy = colors;
    copy[i] = selectedColor;
    setColors(copy);
    // To this:
    // Creating new object with different reference
    let copy = [...colors];
    colors[i] = selectedColor;
    setColors(copy);
  };

  return (
    <div className="grid-container">
      {sides.map((side, i) => (
        <div className={side}>
          <Side setColor={handleColorChange} i={i * 9} colors={colors} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cube;
```